# Electricity in a Lightbulb

Tags: electricity

This may sound incredibly moronically stupid, but where do the electrons in a lightbulb go when it is switched off?

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current)

> An electric current is a flow of electric charge. In electric circuits this charge is often carried by moving electrons in a wire.

The electrons are still there when you switch off the bulb.Its just that once you turn off the lightbulb there is no net force on the electrons and they whizz about in random directions constituting no net flow of charge in any direction and hence no current.

Answer (score 1):

Incandescent light in filaments is a result of [Joule heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating):
$$
\text{Heating Rate}\propto \text{Current}^2 \times\text{Resistance}
$$

It is not the presence of electrons alone, but the rate at which they are being pushed through the material, and how resistive that material, that matters when it comes to generating heat (and therefore light). When you turn the bulb off, the electrons remain but have no net flux - and thus don't cause net heating.